# Почему в исходном коде XML, а при обращении к файлу получаем html?

Tags: php, xml, xmlparser

Здравствуйте.
Вот сайт:
http://www.normacs.ru/Doclist
Если на нем нажать ctrl+u, то увидем xml-код.
Однако если смотреть через инспектор, то будем видеть html.
Проблема при парсинге `(cUrl, getContent,simplexml_load_file)` обрабатывают именно как html.
Как именно обойти проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в начале xml-документа есть строка

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/doclist.xsl"?>
```

Она заставляет браузер применить к XML-документу XSLT преобразование из `doclist.xsl`. Вот и вся магия.

Comment: Спасибо, отмечу ответ как верный. А не подскажите как мне обойти это дело при парсинге?